# What should I do if I want to have several different if statements, all of which of equal priority and an else statement to break a loop?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a piece of code that's supposed to find certain words or other combinations of letters in a two-dimensional array each line of which is of equal length, said words can only be arranged horizontally or vertically, not diagonally. Due to the fact the second letter of the word being searched for can appear next to the first letter of the word being searched for I need to either make several if-like statements that are checked one by one, problem is, all that is contained within a loop that needs to broken if all of them are false. That is unless there is another simpler way and there might most likely is but I'm too mentally drained to come up with it.
here is the part of the code I wrote. I had to scrap the whole thing once because I did it ass-backwards and it didn't work properly if a letter showed up more than once in the two-dimensional array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDNUM 100


int main() {
    char c, word[WORDNUM][100], matrix[10][11];
    int i=0, j=0, lineNum=0, lineLen, a, logLength[WORDNUM], mLine, mLet, wLet, wLine,logExist[WORDNUM]={0}, x, y;
    while (a=1){ //this loop get the words that will be searched for
        c=fgetc(stdin);
        if (isalpha(c)){
            word[i][j]=c;
            j++;
        }
        else if(c==' '){
            logLength[i]=j;
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
        else if(c=='\n'){
            logLength[i]=j;
            i++;
            j=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(fgets(matrix[lineNum], 11, stdin)!=NULL && lineNum < 10){ // this part gets the two-dimensional array
        lineNum++;
    }
    lineLen=strlen(matrix[0])-1;
    for(mLine=0; mLine<lineNum; mLine++){
        for(mLet=0; mLet<lineLen; mLet++){
            wLine=0;
            while(wLine<i){
                if(matrix[mLine][mLet]==word[wLine][0]){
                    wLet=1; x=mLet; y=mLine;
                    while(wLet<logLength[mLine]){
                        //here's the checking of rest of the word and breaking the loop if need be
                        
                    }
                }

                else wLine++;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any and all advice in advance;

Comment: You can use `strncmp()` to test if the word appears horizontally starting at each column of the row.

Comment: For looking vertically, you could make a second matrix with the rows and columns swapped.

Comment: You are trying to solve the problem in a single pass, when it is a three-pass problem. Gather the characters into a 2D array (1st pass), then iterate column-wise, then row-wise to find the words, adding them into a different array.

Comment: Some notes that may be relevant: you need to properly terminate the strings with a `'\0'`; `fgets()` reads and keeps the `'\n'` in the buffer.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: break up the problem into smaller parts, and write a separate function for each sub-problem. I would get mentally drained too, trying to grasp 4 nested loops inside one huge `main` function.

Comment: "*a loop that needs to broken if all of them are false*" -- have you considered `else { break; }`?

Comment: Also of note - not sure if you meant "while (a == 1)" but the current "while (a=1)" is not conventional.  (a = 1) is an assignment, not a logical statement, but might be accidently working for you as a nozero value.